# Neo4j - create hierarchy of new nodes and relationships from property value

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have nodes where each has a property value that represents a hierarchy.  The number of levels in the hierarchy can vary and the existing node always appears at the end of string. The separator is '/'.

An example is:

Property1: '/Level3/Level2/Level1' 
Property2: 'Level1'

Therefore my question is can I use somekind of string function to create new nodes (if they dont exist) for level2, level3, level4 etc and then merge relationships between level 1 - level 2, level 2 - level 3 etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simple example to help you :

```
WITH split("Level2/Level3/Level4/Level5", "/") AS hierarchy 
UNWIND range(1, size(hierarchy)-1) AS i 
MERGE (l1:Level {name: hierarchy[i-1]}) 
MERGE (l2:Level {name: hierarchy[i]}) 
MERGE (l1)-[:PARENT]->(l2)
```

Results in

[image]